# pack angular 2 bundle.js and load it from local file

Tags: angular

Since the vendor.js in angular 2 is very big, I want to package a big vendor.js with every third party package I need and load it from local file in my android app, while load other files such as main.js and index.html from server, how can I do that?

Comment: You probably need to provide information on what you're using for building apps. Are you using phonegap, ionic or which?

Can you show an example of what you currently have?

Comment: @MathijsSegers Sorry, I use angular 2 to develop some modules, and the main part of my app is native, so I want to package the vendor.js file in my app to save load time.  I build my web application using angular cli with  command "ng build -prod --aot -sm=false" and it result in vendor.js main.js  inline.js, the vendor.js file is rather big.

Comment: You should probalby add that information to your question.

So are you saying you're loading a webpage in an iframe, which you want to refer to your webView?

Comment: I would see if you can try to use a file:/ path in your webpage. I have little experience doing this in Android and it seems non-trivial. I could think of some ways to achieve this but they would be quite nasty and I'm not going to suggest going down that path.

Comment: @MathijsSegers So many thanks, I want to package a big bundle.js without "tree shake" so that many web application can use the same bundle.js.